# compare values and keys in multiple array

Tags: php, arrays, key, compare

i have something like below :

```
$array1 = array('first_name'=>'tom','last_name'=>'jackson','city'=>'london');
$array2 = array('last_name'=>'jackson','city'=>'london','first_name'=>'tom');
$array3 = array('city'=>'london','first_name'=>'tom','last_name'=>'jackson');
$array4 = array('last_name'=>'jackson','first_name'=>'tom','city'=>'london');
```

I want to check if all 4 arrays have same key with corresponding values. In above case it must return true as all values with its corresponding keys are same. I can do this using 2 for loops but i am wondering if there any other short cut method to reduce execution time.

Thank you in advance.... :-)

Comment: Please specify programming language on tags and question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all arrays equal $array1 then they are all equal:

```
$array1 == $array2 && $array1 == $array3 && $array1 == $array4
```

This functions does the same:

```
function arrays_equal($arrays) {
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 1, $l = count($arrays); $i < $l; ++$i) {
        if ($arrays[0] != $arrays[$i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if (array_equals($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4)) {
    // all arrays are equal (both keys and values)
}
```